# How to get 2 properties from map function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get 2 properties from an array using the map function. I know it is possible to get 1 property, but I am wanting to get 2 and then display in a string.

```
var us1 = { name: "jim@next.com", role: "QA" }; us2 = { name: "aal@next.com", role: "CFO" }; us3 = { name: "aalon@next.com", role: "CCO" };
var users = [us1, us2, us3];
// here In am getting the user only - i want to also get the role
let user = users.map((i: any) => i.user && i.role);
// put user and role in a string
let result = user.join(" and ");
```

Comment: `&&` is not a string concatenation operator; if you need to concatenate two strings you can use the `+` operator: `let user = row.SignedBy.map((i: any) => (i.user + i.role));`. If you want to be more creative with the fomatting, you can also use a template string: ``let user = row.SignedBy.map((i: any) => `${i.user} (${i.role})`);``

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on how you want those values returned.  For example, you can return them as objects in your new array:

```
row.SignedBy.map((i: any) => ({ user: i.user, role: i.role}))
```

Of course then your subsequent use of `join()` doesn't make sense, because `user` is now an array of *objects* and not *strings*.  If you want them as concatenated strings, build the string you want to return:

```
row.SignedBy.map((i: any) => `${i.user} ${i.role}`)
```

In that case you'd format that string however you want.

Either way, the overall point is that your callback function to `.map()` simply needs to return whatever you want each element in the resulting array to be.  An object, a formatted string, something else, etc.

Answer (score 0):

return `[i.user, i.role]`
then you can spread -> `[...user]`